# Changing link to pop up link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello trying change this link ;

```
 <a href="@String.Format("http://www.koltukcubey.com/chat/index.php?project={0}&member={1}", item.Id, item.Member)" class="theme-btn btn-style-one hvr-bounce-to-right"><span style="float:right;min-width:210px;"></span>GİRİŞ</a><br /><br />
```

To This ;

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('http://www.koltukcubey.com/chat/index.php?project=24&member=2', '', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=1046,height=520'); return false" >Chat sistemine git</a>
```

Comment: And what is happening ?

Comment: @Shyju Well Cant update to onlick with this part {0}&member={1}", item.Id, item.Member)"

Comment: I mean The both work but I need ID and Member on onclick event and I cant figure it out how

Comment: you need the ID and Member where  ? you says it works ! Then what is not working ? What is your expected behaviour ?

Comment: The first link is opening a new window. Second link opens it in pop up. But The second one doesnt get projectId and member Id auto. so the first one need to open in pop up window as second one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not include the window.open part !

This should work fine.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('@String.Format("http://www.koltukcubey.com/chat/index.php?project={0}&member={1}", item.Id,  item.Name)', '', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=1046,height=520'); return false">Thirdt</a>
```